# AngularJS undefined error on $document.context.addEventListener

Tags: angularjs, cordova, opentok, tokbox

I have the following angular service:

```
.factory("OTReady", ['$document', function ($document) {
  var ready = false;
  $document.context.addEventListener('deviceReady', function () {
    ready = true;
  });

  return (function(fn){
    if (ready) {
      fn();
    } else {
      $document.context.addEventListener('deviceReady', fn);
    }
  });
}])
```

And this is returning "undefined". It's a snippet from an [opentok-angular  library](https://github.com/aullman/OpenTok-Angular) running in Cordova.

Many other $document properties are available at in this block of code. Why this is returning "undefined" ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue where my angular linter did not approve of document.addEventListener and was telling me to use the angular $document service like your initial service. However, simply switching `document.addEventListener` to `$document.addEventListener` returned undefined. By printing to the console I figured out `$document` is an array. Not sure if this is intentional or not but changing `$document.addEventListener` to `$document[0].addEventListener` worked for me.

So your new service would look like this:

```
.factory("OTReady", ['$document', function ($document) {
  var ready = false;
  $document[0].addEventListener('deviceReady', function () {
    ready = true;
  });

  return (function(fn){
    if (ready) {
      fn();
    } else {
      $document[0].addEventListener('deviceReady', fn);
    }
  });
}])
```

Someone else should shed some light on why this is set up this way. An array doesn't make much sense unless you might have multiple document objects.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceReady', fn);
```

I read that `context` is being deprecated from jQuery, but I don't think that was the issue.